# What is the voltage between each turn in a transformer winding

Tags: transformer, insulation, winding

From a perspective of insulation, how much voltage between each individual turn in a transformer?

[image: Transformer]

Example from picture above, the primary winding have 16 turns. Let`s say 800VDC is applied between + and -. The core is made of a magical material that never saturates, and the voltage source is capable of infinite current  (just to focus on the voltage insulation part).

Assuming the core itself is perfectly insulated, is the voltage between each turn simply Vp/turns? Or is this more complicated. In this case 50V between 1st to 2nd turn, 50V between turn 7 and 8...etc?

That would model the turns something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFDqIG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But I assume this is not the case since doubling the turns effectively quadruples inductance, instead of doubling it like the above model implicates.

Comment: you are asking about the transient voltage?

Comment: At DC the voltage across an inductor zero, if the winding has resistance then it will be yes 50V for each segment but the transformer will burn due to huge current.

Comment: Steady state peak voltage. I`ll remove my t=0 and pretend this core is of a magical material that never saturates, and of an infinite current source

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you apply 800VDC to such wire with low resistance it will burn as long as it is not superthick. The wire doesn't care about the magical material, the current through the wire will be huge. The power dissipated will be (800*800)/R. Imagine R = 10 Ohm the power need to be dissipated will be 64kW.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. And I don`t really have a magical core material either. My point was simply to not make this a question regarding volt-second balance, copper overheating..etc. Only about how the voltage is distributed (until the copper is eventually destroyed as you mentioned)

Comment: @user164567 Regarding your first comment. Are you stating that DC resistance is a parameter in how voltage is distributed? As in a planar transformer where the winding distance from inner to outer can vary a lot, so will the voltage distribution vary accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty close to \$\frac{v_p}{turns}\$.  Keep in mind, though, that most real transformers have multi-layer windings.  If you're making some super-duper high-voltage transformer the windings can get fancy to avoid too much voltage difference in too small a space.